# Google Admin SDK User access API using Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to fetch and update the Users of my domain using Google Admin API.

```
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();


      GoogleCredential credential =
          new GoogleCredential.Builder()
              .setTransport(httpTransport)
              .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
              .setServiceAccountId(
                  "xxxxx-yyyyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
              .setServiceAccountUser("superadmin@mydomain.com")
              .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                  new File("C:\\privatekey.p12")).build();

      Directory admin =
          new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
              .setApplicationName("User Sync Service")
              .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

      Directory.Users.List list = admin.users().list();
      Users users = list.execute();
      System.out.println("************");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

From my Google Console

[image]
[image]

1. API Access is enabled from my Security panel
2. ServiceAccountUser is Super Admin.

But I am still getting this error

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:269)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

**Update:**
Screenshot from ManageOath

[image]

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this? I am kind of in the same situation

Comment: @user1076371, yes. I can help you with this since Google Doc is quite misleading

Comment: can you post how you fixed the problem? Thanks!

Comment: It's bit hard to say. But Can you post screenshot from Oauth Token Screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is somewhat ambiguous about customer and domain. One or the other must be specified.  You can set the `customer` attribute when using the list() function. It should be set to the customer's ID (a unique, random looking string) or, if you're authenticating as an admin already in the Google Apps instance, you can just specify exactly `customer=my_customer`. Alternatively, you can specify `domain=example.com` where example.com is a primary or secondary domain in the Google Apps instance. When specifiying a domain, only users who have a primary (home) address in that domain will be returned in the results. When specifying customer, all users in the Google Apps instance will be returned.

You can confirm this using the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/admin/directory_v1/directory.users.list). Leaving customer blank always results in an error. However, putting `my_customer` for customer attribute should fix it.

Comment: Still I am getting same error. Tried with setDomain and setCustomer.

Comment: Google API Explorer is also throwing error even if i fill Customer and domain or individually both details

Comment: @JayLee u there i need one help on this issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify either the domain or the customer parameter:

```
Directory.Users.List list = admin.users().list()
   .setDomain("<target_domain>");

// or

Directory.Users.List list = admin.users().list()
   .setCustomer("<target_customer_id>");
```

I filed a bug to update the docs to make it clear that at least one of those two parameters is required.

Comment: Still I am getting same error. Tried with setDomain and setCustomer.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed to https://admin.google.com/*yourdomain*/ManageOauthClients and check that those scopes are added for your xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com service account id.

Comment: It's already there. and I updated the original post with screenshot too

Comment: What happens if you just drop setApplicationName("User Sync Service")
and setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)?

Comment: Sorry, your code looks good to me. Other than it, it could be the privatekey file...

Comment: I deleted exisiting service account and created new one. Still same error

Comment: I tried this https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get
by giving my email address, it eventually pulled the user without a issue